# Android Gridview : Drag an item

Tags: java, android, gridview, draggable, drag

I thank who try to help me, is so important for me...

I'm trying to implement a drag for an item that is inside of a gridview, I saw so much examples avaible on internet but can't understand :/

I have a gridview into my xml with diferents images:

```
<GridView 
android:id="@+id/contenedorPictogramas"
android:layout_width="780dp" 
android:layout_height="520dp"
android:columnWidth="160dp"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:verticalSpacing="20dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/shape"
/>
```

and I use a method that I use to drag another images:

```
private final class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
      if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
        view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
```

To set the images into the gridview I tried to do this:

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.contenedorPictogramas);
gridview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {         
      public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
          arg0.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());//HERE IS THE PROBLEM (I THING)
          return false;
      }
  });
```

but i drag all items of the gridview :/

Answer (score 0):

You should **set the on touch Listener for the grid view items** not on the grid view.

You can add the touch listener inside the getview method of your adapter.

sample-

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
**imageView.setOnTouchListener(<your listener>);**
        return imageView;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought this, but I don't know how set the items, I tried to set an item but i can't do it: 

gridview.getItemAtPosition(1).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener()); do you have any idea how I can do it?

Comment: inside the getView() of your grid adapter.refer edited answer